# If the US decided to inflate its way out of their debt, what would the value of the dollar drop to?

Tags: united-states, debt, currency, money-supply

Hypothetically, what would the value of the US dollar drop to if the US government decided it wanted to inflate its way out of their national debt all at once? Would it simply be:

> M2 money supply / (M2 money supply + debt)

or

> $13.5 trillion / ($13.5 trillion + $20 trillion) = 0.40

Which would be 40% of its current value?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's about a hypothetical situation, that is both unlikely to occur and hasn't got a definite answer (therefore being opinion based)

Comment: This seems like an interesting question, though possibly a better fit for [SE.Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For the political aspect of paying off the debt via printing money all at once, that doesn't seem to make much sense.  For example, about two thirds of the US debt is to itself, so why would it undergo rapid inflation to pay it?

Comment: @Nat What does "itself" mean here?

Comment: @immibis The US, in the sense of the collection of entities that'd consider themselves part of the US, including the federal/state governments/institutions, US corporations and parts of international corporations in the US, US citizens, etc..

Comment: @Nat  The US would be less likely to have inflation for debt bought from foreign entities.  Paying them back would cause currency fluctuations or a stock market bull market more than inflation.  It's the domestic money paid back that causes inflation.  Foreign money only matters if it turns around and turns into domestic consumption.

Comment: @Nat So what you're saying is some US government entities have debt to other US government entities. Why would they *not* pay off that debt? Those are perfectly valid debts and if you don't pay them off then you are not paying off all debts.

Comment: @immibis The issue isn't whether to pay debts, but rather printing money to meet all of those obligations.

Comment: @Brythan That does sound like an interesting set of reactions that'd go off around the globe.  This would've been a fun thread for a discussion forum!

Comment: @Nat Well, the question is "if money was printed to pay all current debts", and those are current debts, and you're talking about how money might not be printed to pay them, which is entirely invalid in the context of the question that asks about the situation where money *is* printed to pay them.

Comment: @immibis I think that there's been a miscommunication here.  My point was that the proposed solution - printing money to pay down all debts isn't a particularly sensible approach.  To clarify, the question above cites the total debt, not current debt (in the sense of what needs to be paid now).

Comment: By "current debt" I meant "all debt that exists currently", apologies if that's an actual economic term that means something else.

Comment: I would think it would be closer to the monetary base (all the money the US have ever created, about $3.8 trillion) divided by the total debt ($20 trillion), since each dollar (Federal Reserve Note) holder would now own that much smaller a portion of all money created. However, that's purely theoretical because other governments also inflate currency, prices tend to increase regardless, and economics can be complex. The concept of printing (well minting) our way out of debt was discussed seriously in 2011: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trillion_dollar_coin

Comment: Googling "donald trump we can print out way out of debt" (no quotes) shows that President Trump has also considered this method more recently.

Comment: @Brythan domestic consumption is the whole reason foreigners value your money to begin with.